# Geth windows console - get Transaction and balance problem

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, rinkeby

I have setup a geth client in windows.  By using below command I am able to run geth.

```
geth --rinkeby --verbosity "0" console
```

I created an account then pasted my public key on twitter to get funded by Faucet of Rinkeby, it was success, I can see my balance on Rinkeby web ui.

But when I send query about my balance from geth win cli, it is still 0. `getTransactionCount()` is also 0.

when I do eth.syncing this is the output:

```
{
  currentBlock: 791043,
  highestBlock: 1772520,
  knownStates: 1607660,
  pulledStates: 1599109,
  startingBlock: 35346
}
```

According to Rinkeby web ui my transaction  is in 1772468 th block

So why I can't see my balance, what does currentBlock mean in syncing function? Does that means my node hasn't synced with the blocks between current and highest block and behaves according to state at current block?

Confused.

Thanks

Comment: Until it has finished syncing geth will not return meaningful data.

Comment: What if our transactions are out of the interval between starting block and highest block of local node? How can we see the balance in that case?

Comment: You will have to wait until it has finished syncing. If you can't wait you can try using a node from infura.io or check by hand in a explorer like rinkeby.etherscan.io

Comment: Highest node increasing faster than current block and there are 65 blocks difference, with this speed It will never be sync'd with most recent block. Is it normal?

Comment: Do you have a SSD? How much RAM do you have? Are you using linux, windows or macos? What version of geth are you using? I'd recommend a SSD with over 50Gb free, 8 Gb of RAM.

Comment: Win - Not SSD - 8 GB ram. Solved with --cache=128 , thanks.

Comment: There is a new version of geth v1.8 which has some improvements for HDD, with your RAM you can try with a larger cache, ie 256 or 512.

Answer (score 0):

`currentBlock` indicates how  far `geth` has sync'd so far. So you see a zero balance because that's what the balance for that account was at block 791043. To use `geth` to check the current balance, you'll have to wait until you've sync'd up to the most recent block.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you face any issue, verbosity will help you to identify what was issue. You provided verbosity value is 0 that means it will show any logs.

To modify verbosity

> $> geth attach  <>
>
> geth> debug.verbosity(4)

If you run above command you can able to know what's going on in your geth client. Verbosity value will start from 0 to 6. By default its 3.

I guess geth client is not completed sync with rinkeby network. So that a reason its not showing balance.